# Shiny Tab Hide/Show

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have created a hide tab checkbox to hide the tabs for which i have mentioned the condition in server. I want to replace the checkbox or hide the checkbox after mentioning the default value as TRUE or FALSE. So that once the app runs, the user cannot see the TABS which are hidden. Please review below code.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(datasets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Test of Skills"),

  sidebarLayout(

    sidebarPanel(("Details Enter Page"),

                 checkboxInput(inputId = "hide_tab",label = "Hide 'Data Selected' tab"),

                 # selectInput(inputId = "hide_tab",label = "Hide 'Data Selected' tab",choices = c(TRUE,FALSE), multiple = FALSE),

                 selectInput("data", "Select the dataset which has to be selected for analysis", 

                             choices = c("iris" , "pressure" , "USArrests")),

                 radioButtons("color", "Select the color of the histogram", 
                              choices = c("green", "orange","red","pink")),

                 sliderInput("bins", "select the number of bins required for histogram", 
                             min = 5 , max = 25 , value = 5 , step = 1),

                 numericInput("obs" , "Select the number of observation required for dataset" , 

                              min = 5, max = 100 , value = 5 , step = 1),

                 submitButton("Confirm")),

    mainPanel((" Analysis Of the Dataset"),

              tabsetPanel(id = "my_tabs",type = c("pills"),

                          tabPanel("Summary", h1(textOutput("MysumHeader")) ,
                                   verbatimTextOutput("Mysum")),

                          tabPanel("Structure and Observation" , h1(textOutput("Mystrobsheader")),
                                   verbatimTextOutput("Mystr") , h1(textOutput("Myobsheader")), verbatimTextOutput("Myobs")),

                          tabPanel("Data Selected",tableOutput("Mydata")),

                          tabPanel("Histogram Plot"))
    ))))




server <- shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  observeEvent(input$hide_tab,ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = TRUE, {
    if(isTRUE(input$hide_tab)) {
      shiny::hideTab(inputId = "my_tabs",
                     target = "Summary")
      shiny::hideTab(inputId = "my_tabs",
                     target = "Histogram Plot")
    } else {
      shiny::showTab(inputId = "my_tabs",
                     target = "Summary")
      shiny::showTab(inputId = "my_tabs",
                     target = "Histogram Plot")
    }

  })

  output$Mysum <- renderPrint({

    summary(get(input$data))
  })
  output$MysumHeader <- renderText({

    paste("The Dataset which is selected for analysis" , input$data)
  })

  output$Mystr <- renderPrint({

    str(get(input$data))
  })

  output$Mystrobsheader <- renderText({

    paste("DataSet selected for structure is " , input$data)
  })

  output$Myobs <- renderPrint({

    head(get((input$data)))

  })

  output$Myobsheader <- renderText({

    paste("First" , input$obs , "Selected from the datase" , input$data)

  })

  output$Mydata <- renderTable({

    View(get(input$data))
  })

})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: So what is it you want to hide, that tab or the checkbox?

Comment: I am hiding the tabs with the use of checkbox, i even want to hide the checkbox, so that after running the code, user cannot make changes using the checkbox

Comment: you should look at the functions ```hide``` and ```show``` in the package ```shinyjs```